# Hacer una matriz a partir de un ListBox en C#

Tags: c#, matrices

Tengo estos datos en el ListBox al cual llamé bc:

```
ABCF
GHTP
HUJI
```

Y este código:

```
bc = new String[lbReglas.Items.Count, lbReglas.Items[0].ToString().Split().Count()];
for (int i = 0; i < bc.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < bc.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        bc[i, j] = Convert.ToString(lbReglas.Items[i].ToString().Split()[j]);
    }

}
```

Lo que me resulta es una matriz de 3 filas por 1 columna y mi problema es en las columnas, lo que quiero es que me resulte 3 filas por 4 columnas(el numero de columnas depende del tamaño de la cadena que yo ingrese) ya que la primera cadena es ABCF... y que me arroje una matriz tipo:

```
bc[0,0]=A
bc[0,1]=B
bc[0,2]=C
bc[0,3]=F
bc[1,0]=G
bc[1,1]=H
bc[1,2]=T
bc[1,3]=P
bc[2,0]=H
bc[2,1]=U
bc[2,2]=J
bc[2,3]=I
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el codigo usas `Split()` pero no haces split por ningun caracter, tienes que separar de alguna forma.

```
string[,] bc = new string[lbReglas.Items.Count, 4];

for (int i = 0; i < bc.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    char[] letras = lbReglas.Items[i].ToString().ToCharArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < bc.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        bc[i, j] = Convert.ToString(letras[j]);
    }

}
```

Un `string` basicamente es un `char[]` por lo que puede tomar cada letra sin ningun split

[C# | ToCharArray() Method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-tochararray-method/)

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!